# How to run Blender as a Service?

Tags: services, blender, background-process

I have a python script that continually calls blender to do some rendering with various blend files

```
os.system('blender -b testFile.blend --python-text render -- [args]')
```

This call will open blender in background and do some render and then close blender for multiple files at any time. Is there a way to keep blender open always in the background, perhaps as a service? Can't afford the time lost to always open blender and close since time and efficiency is of essence.

Comment: You are already using blender in headless mode in the back-ground … So there is no blender opening actually but rather there is blender directly rendering … Therefore, AFAIK it appears this might be the fastest available method so far … as the needed libraries will still be loaded in memory throughout multiple calls

Comment: don't use os.system. use `requests` and you can create a session and use a `keep alive`.

Comment: hey thank you! i googled this and only found http request examples. how do i.rewrite the command in my question to use requests with keep alive? can u kindly post it as answer?